# Efficient MapReduce when dealing with streams to queries to the same dataset

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I have a massive, static dataset and I've a function to apply to it.

f is in the form reduce(map(f, dataset)), so I would use the MapReduce skeleton. However, I don't want to scatter the data at each request (and ideally I want to take advantage of indexing in order to speedup f). There is a MapReduce implementation that address this general case?

I've taken a look at [IterativeMapReduce](http://www.iterativemapreduce.org/) and maybe it does the job, but seems to address a slightly different case, and the code isn't available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop's MapReduce (and all the others map-reduce skeleton inspired by Google) doesn't scatter the data all the time.